# Can we compile and run typescript in angular at runtime?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was thinking about using the HttpClient to download, compile, and run a Typescript file at runtime.  Anyone know if Angular has an API for doing this (The compile and run part)?

Just to be clear the application will already be compiled and will be running.  It will then download, compile, and run additional typescript files as needed.  Similar to using `eval` in Javascript.

Comment: This is not possible, angular has its development guide lines, it could be considered as bad practice

Comment: It is definately possible, there is noting that makes it impossible, it is just not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add TypeScript to your app to transpile TypeScript to JavaScript but why would you want to? If it is downloading the code you should be building the code before deploying it.

Comment: I was thinking about deploying a Table of Contents Typescript file along with markdown content and the content and the file could be updated at the same time.  The Typescript file could have functions that offered various different views of the table of contents.  I could also divide this into static JSON and do the views at compile time, but I thought it would be neat if it could be done dynamically.

Comment: JSON is the way to go, not TypeScript.

Comment: Yeah-I agree with you.